# How to spawn objects that grow independently in processing

Tags: processing, p5.js

If I wanted to make a circle grow larger: I would make a variable for the X and Y coords and have them increase each step.

But if I made 10 circles for example then how would I go about having them all increase in size independent of one another?

Comment: Use an array? Any decent book/tutorial on p5.js should explain how they work in JavaScript.

Comment: I already have a setup for making the circles but they all spawn at the same size. I want them to all spawn at a starting size (let’s say 10 for example) and then have them all grow in size to 100. My issue is if one circle has a size of 20, all of the other circles will spawn at that size. I know the issue is that they’re all using the same variable, but I don’t know how to have them all grow independently.

Comment: You would need to show your code if you are having problems with it. It is hard to say much without seeing a [mcve]. It would be natural to define circle objects, each with their own radius and grow method. Have an array of such objects. Initialize them so that they have different radii.

Comment: var r;
var g;
var b;
var a;

var diam;
var x;
var y;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(480, 270);
  background(255);
}

function draw() {
  r = random(255);
  g = random(255);
  b = random(255);
  a = random(255);
  diam = random(20);
  x = random(width);
  y = random(height);

  noStroke();
  fill(r, g, b, a);
  ellipse(x, y, diam, diam);
}

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using an object literal, or a function object (in JavaScript 5) or a class (in JavaScript 6).

Here's an example of an object literal:

```
// create a circle
var myCircle = {x:25, y:75, size:50};

// move a circle
myCircle.x += 10;

// draw a circle
ellipse(myCircle.x, myCircle.y, myCircle.size
```

You could then create an **array** of these object literals.

Here's an example of a function object:

```
// define Circle function object
function Circle(x, y, size){
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.size = size;
}

// create a circle
var myCircle = new Circle(25, 75, 50);

// move a circle
myCircle.x += 10;

// draw a circle
ellipse(myCircle.x, myCircle.y, myCircle.size);
```

Again, you could then create an array of circles.

Here's an example of a class:

```
// define Circle class
class Circle{
  constructor(x, y, size){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.size = size;
  }
}

// create a circle
var myCircle = new Circle(25, 75, 50);

// move a circle
myCircle.x += 10;

// draw a circle
ellipse(myCircle.x, myCircle.y, myCircle.size);
```

Of course, you can still create an array of circles.

Shameless self-promotion: [here](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/javascript/creating-objects) is a tutorial on creating objects in JavaScript. You can also google something like "javascript arrays" for a ton of results. Good luck.